# go return child type from parent function

Tags: go

I am still fairly new to Go.

Is it possible to return a child type from an embedded parent function?

Something along the lines of the following code:

```
type Humans struct {
    NextPage string
}

type Employees struct {
    Humans 
    Items []struct {
        Stuff string
        DifferentStuff float64
    }      
}

func (h *Human) Next() interface{} {
    list interface{}
    jsonGet(h.NextPage, &list)
    return list
}

func main() {
    list := Employees{}
    jsonGet("http://blah.blah", &list)
    for ; list != nil; list = list.Next() {
         for _, item := range list.Items {
             ... do stuff ...
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate your requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

Embedding is not inheritance.